# HTML/CSS - long words replaced with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really don't know how to call it so I can't find a good search.

I'm trying to break a word but instead of putting the word in the next line, I'd replace the letters at the end of the container with ...
More like that on Facebook posts with a see more option that appears.

How do I do it?

Comment: It's not possible with just html and css. Using Javascript may help you achieve this.

Comment: it can be achieve with javaScript only

Comment: Don't know why I got a minus in reputation. And I dunno why they edited it putting javascript in the tags when a css answer has been given (and I'm looking for a css answer). Thanks anyway~

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of css property ellipsis in which it truncates the length of follow it up with '...'

```
.your_class {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

A lot more can be learned from this [tutorial-ellipsis tricks](http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1198/)

```
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

#div2
 {
   white-space:nowrap; 
   width:12em; 
   overflow:hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis; 
   border:1px solid #000000;
 }
```